# Case sensitive routing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking for case sensitive routing in ASP.NET Core 2.2 application.

For example:

```
[HttpGet("/yes}")]
public IActionResult Test()
```

**domain.com/yes** and **domain.com/YES** going to same action. But I want this to be completely case sensitive.

https://www.visualupload.com/u/2CU

https://www.visualupload.com/U/2CU (u is uppercase and both working.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: For info, this is very unusual behaviour and generally frowned upon.

Comment: This looks like Pandora's box, both in terms of usability and SEO.

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you elaborate on the use case of why this is desired?

Comment: For search engine optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other posters have mentioned I would strongly discourage this operation, as it can be a nightmare for a number of reasons.  However, it would be possible to do this, using the default routes.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult MyAction(string id){ }
}
```

The standard routing process would pass the request of `/My/MyAction/TeST` to your MyAction method.

You could then have conditional logic to do your case-sensitive stuff inside of the MyAction method.

Again, this isn't a recommended approach, but it is one way you could accomplish the goal.

Edited: Inside of this you might have something similar to this

```
switch(id)
{
    case "lowercase":
        return MyLowercaseAction();
    case "MiXeDcAsE":
        return MyMixedCaseAction();
    //etc.
}
```

You would then have individual methods that returned action results for the various scenarios.  Or whatever else you needed to do.  The key is that you will receive the information and need to take the case-sensitive action on your own.

Comment: Thanks. Should I invoke by reflection after that?

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu no need for reflection, you could just call your different actions after that.  I'll edit the reply

Comment: I think this is only way to do it... Thanks.